# For Loop to play sound in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of sounds on my serveur called:

**sound1.mp3,
 sound2.mp3,
 sound3.mp3
...**

I also have a list of pictures called:
**image1.jpg,
image2.jpg,
image3.jpg
...**

I would like to play the sound1.mp3 when clicking the image1.jpg, 
the sound2.mp3 when pressing the image2.jpg, etc.. etc..

I'm not very good at javascript and I struggle with the quotations "" and ''..

```
<script>
function playSound(){
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) { 
        '<audio id="sound' + i +'" src="mywebsite/sound'+ i + '.mp3"></audio>'
        '<img src="mywebsite/image' + i + '.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById("sound"\i"\").play()"/>';
}
}
playSound();
</script>
```

Thanks very much for any help... !!!

Comment: what eror you getting ?

Comment: Just to let you know this what finally worked for me! Many thanks.

<script>
function playSound()
{
 var strHTML = '';

 for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++)
 {
  strHTML += '<audio id="word' + i +'" src="/media/website/word'+ i + '.mp3"></audio>';
  strHTML += '<img src="/media/website/word' + i + '.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById(\'word' + i + '\').play()" /><hr/>';
 }

 document.getElementById('sound_container').innerHTML = strHTML;
}
playSound();
</script>
<div id="sound_container"></div>

Answer (score 2):

You can start playback of a single file with something like this:

```
var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
audio.play();
```

If you want to play successive files, you will need to capture the `ended` event, like this:

```
function playFirstTwoFiles() {
    var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
    audio.addEventListener("ended", playSecondFile, true);
    audio.play();
}

function playSecondFile() {
    var audio = new Audio('audio_file_2.mp3');
    audio.play();
}
```

Comment: I like this answer because you do it all in script. I imagine the best solution will work for `n` number of songs and does not require a method implementation per song. If you move an index through a song array for example, you can recursively call a `playSong` function that continues to load the next song in the list.

Comment: I don't understand really this code sorry... What is the full code with the HTML codes?

Comment: No HTML codes are required in this solution, it is 100% script.

Comment: Thanks John this what's finally worked for me but I couldn't figure out how to do with your code sorry =) Many Thanks !!


<script>
function playSound()
{
 var strHTML = '';

 for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++)
 {
  strHTML += '<audio id="word' + i +'" src="/media/website/word'+ i + '.mp3"></audio>';
  strHTML += '<img src="/media/website/word' + i + '.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById(\'word' + i + '\').play()" /><hr/>';
 }

 document.getElementById('sound_container').innerHTML = strHTML;
}
playSound();
</script> <div id="sound_container"></div>

Answer (score 1):

Run below snippet and Check console html string is there as per you expected.

```js
function playSound(){
   var htmltoappend = "";
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) { 
       htmltoappend += '<audio id="sound' + i +'" src="mywebsite/sound'+ i + '.mp3"></audio>'
         htmltoappend += '<img src="mywebsite/image' + i + '.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById("sound'+i+'").play()"/>';
}
  console.log(htmltoappend);
}
playSound();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. I getting some trouble with my code still but I don't know why.

https://afmelbourne.sslsvc.com/social/the-easiest-french-lesson-on-earth/

I checked the console nut I'm not sure what's wrong...
​

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your line 5 as follows

```
'<img src="mywebsite/image' + i + '.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById("sound' + i + '").play()"/>'
```